# Aliasing with a name similar to a class name

Tags: php, class, namespaces, alias

In php.net there is an example that I didn't understand:

```
<?php
namespace foo;
use My\Full\Classname as Another;

// this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname
use My\Full\NSname;

// importing a global class
use ArrayObject;

$obj = new namespace\Another; // instantiates object of class foo\Another
$obj = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
NSname\subns\func(); // calls function My\Full\NSname\subns\func
$a = new ArrayObject(array(1)); // instantiates object of class ArrayObject
// without the "use ArrayObject" we would instantiate an object of class foo\ArrayObject
?>
```

From here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

How can they say in this statement `$obj = new namespace\Another;` that it instantiate an object from the class `foo\another`? When I tried to add a definition to the class `Another` I got an error that says that the Another name is already in use (because it is an alias).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if the `foo\Another` class is defined in another file without such alias.

*another.php*

```
<?php

namespace foo;

class Another { }
```

*test.php*

```
<?php

namespace foo;
use My\Full\Classname as Another;

require_once 'another.php';

new namespace\Another;
```

The example given is to illustrate namespace resolution and conveniently ignores other details and conflicts which may arise.